# How to deny clients' connection properly in socket programming?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a program which works as a simple tcp server, it will accept and serve as much as 4 clients. I wrote the following code snippet to archive this goal, for more clearly, I replace some MACRO with "magic number".

```
while(1) {
  int ret = 0;
  ///
  // sock_ is the listening socket, rset_conn_ only contains sock_
  //
  if(select(sock_ + 1, &rset_conn_, NULL, NULL, &timeo_) <= 0) {
    ret = 0;
  }

  if(FD_ISSET(sock_, &rset_conn_)) {
    ret = 1;
  }

  /// 
  // because the rule select() clears file descriptor and updates timeout is 
  // complex, for simplicity, let's reset the sock_ and timeout
  //
  FD_SET(sock_, &rset_conn_);
  timeo_.tv_sec = 0;
  timeo_.tv_usec = 500000;

  if(! ret) {
    continue ;
  }

  ///
  // csocks_ is an 4 integer array, used for storing clients' socket
  //
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i) {
    if((-1 == csocks_[i]) && (-1 != (csocks_[i] = accept(sock_, NULL, NULL)))) {
      break ;
    }
  }
}
```

now, when less than 4 clients connect, this code snippet works normally, but when the 5th client connects, as you can see, it will not be accepted in the *for* loop, this results in such a problem: in the following loops of *while*, select() call keeps returning with *sock_* bit in *rset_conn_* set --- just because I don't accept it!!

I realize that I should not just ignoring it(not accept) in the *for* loop, but how can I handle it properly by telling kernel "I don't want to accept this client, so not tell me this client want to connect me any more!"?

Any help will be appreciated..

**Update:**

I can not stop calling select() call, because the clients already connected may disconnect, and then my program will have room for new clients. I need to **keep** listening on a socket to accept connection, not stop listening when reaches one point.

Comment: "I need to keep listening on a socket to accept connection" : No, you don't. You could just as easily bang on the *client* sockets (which I assume you're doing *regardless*), and  resume the listening loop once you detect a drop-off. It seems to me you're trying to hand-roll your own `listen()`. That is a wheel I would advise against reinventing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you asking a question you don't want the answer to? Stop calling `select` on the listening socket if you don't want to be told that there's an unaccepted connection.

> I can not stop calling select() call, because the clients already connected may disconnect, and then my program will have room for new clients. I need to keep listening on a socket to accept connection, not stop listening when reaches one point.

You can stop calling select *now*. When a client disconnects, then start calling `select` again. Only ask questions you want the answers to.

Comment: I have updated the reason why I can't stop calling `select()`

Comment: Ah... the method you say is somewhat a coding skill, actually, I want to know if there is a way to tell the kernel ignore this client *this time*? Or if I can handle this connection by just sending a RST packet, so I have handled this connection that `select` will not bother me again?

Comment: `accept`/`close`. Do not forget to set the listening socket non-blocking!

Comment: @Cifer You're confused between 'stop calling select() *on the listening socket*' and 'stop calling select()'. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

There is no socket API to tell the kernel to ignore pending connections (well, on Windows, there is a callback in `WSAAccept()` for that, but that is a Microsoft-specific extension).

On most platforms, you have to either:

1. `close()` the listening socket when your array fills up, then reopen it when a client disconnects.
2. `accept()` the client but immediately `close()` it if the array is full.
3. stop calling `select()` and `accept()` while your array is full.  Any clients that are in the backlog will time out eventually, unless your array fills up and you `accept()` a pending client before it times out.

Comment: Actually in non-blocking mode there is. Just don't select on the listening socket.

Comment: Avoiding `select()` does not stop the OS from putting pending clients into the listening socket's backlog queue, where they will sit until the app calls `accept()` or the clients timeout and disconnect on their end.

Comment: It's okay to me to avoid selecting on the listening socket. `accept()` and immediately `close()` seems a little redundant and troublesome. I think that OS should provide us an interface that we can refuse the client's connection, like sending back a RST message.

Comment: It is not redundant. `accept()` gets the client out of the queue, and then `close()` disconnects the connection. Depending on the socket's LINGER settings, you may be able to create an abortive disconnect that triggers a `RST`. But as long as the client remains in the queue, it thinks it is still trying to connection. If you want to tell the client to go away immediately, you have to initiate that, you can't just ignore the client or it will not know.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the listening socket from the readFDs while there are four existing clients, and put it back when one drops off, but I don't see the point. Why only four clients? Why not remove the limit and eliminate the whole problem? Real servers are not built this way.

Comment: Thanks very much! I got it. It's a design issue, the number is 32 in reality, I reduced it to 4 here just for simplicity.

Comment: And, this program is running on embedded devices, I don't want this program run out of the system resources.

Comment: Note that this won't refuse connections while you're not selecting on the listening socket. They will just queue up, but that seems to be preferable anyway to me. When the backlog queue fills you will start to get connection refusals or timeouts, depending on the platform's behaviour.